# Unistall Vim Mac Os High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: macos, vim, macos-high-sierra

I don't know why I ever wanted to install it on my machine.
Please can someone help me unistall it?
Haven't found anywhere tips or resources on how to do that.

I have Homebrew installed and I have already tried

```
brew uninstall --force vim
```

and

```
brew uninstall macvim
```

Comment: What does `which vim` show?

Comment: It shows '/usr/bin/vim'

Comment: Thanks for your good question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

brew installs software in `/usr/local/bin/`.

In `/usr/bin` (since OS X El Capitan) you can only find applications that have been shipped with macOS itself, so `/usr/bin/vim` is part of the system and can't be uninstalled.

Tools like brew or macports should use `/usr/local` or `/opt` to prefix their installation paths.

The whole `/usr` directory except `/usr/local` is under [Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899), which means that you cannot change its content even with `sudo`.

> [...]System Integrity Protection is designed to allow modification of these protected parts only by processes that are signed by Apple and have special entitlements to write to system files, such as Apple software updates and Apple installers.[...]
>
> System Integrity Protection includes protection for these parts of the system:
>
> - /System
> - /usr
> - /bin
> - /sbin
> - Apps that are pre-installed with OS X
>
> Paths and apps that third-party apps and installers can continue to write to include:
>
> - /Applications
> - /Library
> - /usr/local

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know why I ever wanted to install it on my machine.

Well, it was already there so yeah, why did you install another one?

> Please can someone help me unistall it?

We certainly can… if you tell us how you installed it as the exact method will be different if you installed it from source, via MacPorts, via homebrew, or any another method. If you even installed it, that is.

FWIW, Vim has always been installed at `/usr/bin/vim` on Mac OS X since forever. If `$ ls -l /usr/bin/vim` ends with `/usr/bin/vim` you can stop worrying now as your system is pretty much OK. If not, show us the whole line so that we can go further.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wanted to remove it because I'm using gitlab and every time I commit it opens and that's pretty annoying

Comment: change your default editor rather than delete every editor that isn't the one you want to use.  
(same applies to default difftool)